# Integrating $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$ without the residue theorem?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, complex-integration

Consider the integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$$
Are there any other ways to compute this integral besides using the residue theorem?

Edit: Thank you all, kind people, for the answers. I had this on an exam and solved it with the residue theorem and was just wondering what other ways are possible and which of those do not involve complex integration.

Comment: How would you integrate this with the residue theorem?  From there, you might use the proof of the residue theorem to do so without.

Comment: Note that $\cos x = \mathfrak R (e^{ix})$.

Comment: I've added a second solution assuming that we know $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(tx)}{1+x^2} dt = \frac{1}{2}\pi e^{-t}$$

Answer (score 4):

Let us define integral with parameter:

\begin{align}
I(t) = \int_0 ^\infty \frac{\cos(xt)}{(1+x^2)^2}dt.
\end{align}

Taking the derivative of I:
\begin{align}
\frac{dI}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}  \int_0 ^\infty \frac{\cos(xt)}{(1+x^2)^2}dt
=\int_0 ^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \frac{\cos(xt)}{(1+x^2)^2}dt= - \int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin(xt)}{(1+x^2)^2}dt.
\end{align}

Taking the second derivative:
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2I}{dt^2} = -\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2\cos(xt)}{(1+x^2)^2}dt =
 -\int_0^\infty \frac{(1+x^2-1)\cos(xt)}{(1+x^2)^2}dt = 
 -\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(xt)}{(1+x^2)}dt + \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(xt)}{(1+x^2)^2}dt
\end{align}

From here we get:
\begin{align}
I’’(t) = -\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(tx)}{1+x^2} dt + I(t)
\end{align}

It is well known that(you can derive it similar to this metdod):

\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(tx)}{1+x^2} dt = \frac{\pi}{2} e^{-t}
\end{equation}

So we get differential equation:

\begin{align}
I’’(t) - I(t) = -\frac{\pi}{2} e^{-t}
\end{align}

Th general solution is of the form is:
\begin{equation}
I(t) = Ae^{-t} + Be^{t}
\end{equation}

And paticular solution will be of the form $I(t) = Cte^{-t}$ and the we calculate $I’’(t) - I(t)$ to get $C = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

So final form is :
\begin{align}
I(t) = Ae^{-t} + Be^t + \frac{\pi}{4}e^{-t} t
\end{align}

To get $A$ and $B$ we calculate $I(0)$ and $I’(0)$:
\begin{align}
I(0) = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2} dt
\end{align}
U-sub: $u=\tan{\theta}, du = \frac{1}{\cos^2{\theta}} d\theta$

We get:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{(1+\tan^2{\theta})^2} \frac{1}{\cos^2(\theta)} dt = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^2(\theta) d\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}
\end{equation}

It is obvious that $I’(0) = 0$. After pluging in $I(t)$ and calculating $A$ and $B$ we get:
\begin{equation}
I(t) = \frac{\pi}{4}(xe^{-x} + e^{-x}).
\end{equation}

Our answer is : $I(1) = \frac{\pi}{4}(2e^{-1}) = \frac{\pi}{2e}.$

Comment: The value of the integral is $\frac\pi{2e}$.

Comment: It should be $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(tx)}{1+x^2} dt = \frac{1}{2}\pi e^{-t}$$

Comment: Thank you for your remarks I fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\displaystyle f(\lambda) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\lambda x)}{(1+x^2)^2}\;{ \mathrm dx}$. Consider the Laplace transform of $f(\lambda)$.

$$\begin{aligned}\mathcal{L}(f(\lambda)) & = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\lambda x)}{(1+x^2)^2}e^{-\lambda s}\;{\mathrm d\lambda }\;{\mathrm dx} \\&= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{s}{(1+x^2)^2(s^2+x^2)}\;{\mathrm dx} \\& = \frac{\pi(2+s)}{4(1+s)^2}.\end{aligned} $$

Thus $ \displaystyle f(\lambda ) =\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi(2+s)}{4(1+s)^2}\right) =\frac{\pi}{4}e^{-\lambda}(1+\lambda)$.

The value of the integral is $\displaystyle I = f(1) = \frac{\pi}{2e}. $

---

---

---

Let $\displaystyle I(\lambda) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos( x)}{\lambda^2+x^2}$. Let $x \mapsto \lambda x$ then

$\displaystyle I(\lambda) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos( \lambda x)}{\lambda^2+\lambda^2x^2} \, \mathrm d \lambda x = \frac{1}{\lambda}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos( \lambda x)}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm d x = \frac{\pi}{2\lambda e^{-\lambda}}  $.

Differentiating both sides

$\displaystyle I'(\lambda) = -\int_0^{\infty} \frac{2 \lambda \cos( x)}{(\lambda^2+x^2)^2} \, \mathrm d \lambda =  -\frac{(\lambda +1) \pi}{2 \lambda e ^{\lambda}}.  $

This gives

$\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos( x)}{(\lambda^2+x^2)^2} \, \mathrm d \lambda =  \frac{ \pi (\lambda+1)}{4\lambda^3 e ^{\lambda}} $

With $\lambda = 1$ this gives $\displaystyle I = \frac{\pi}{2 e}.$

Answer (score 1):

Writing
$$\frac 1{(x^2+1)^2}=\frac{2}{(i+1)^3 (x+i)}+\frac{1}{(i+1)^2 (x+i)^2}-\frac{2}{(i+1)^3
   (x-i)}+\frac{1}{(i+1)^2 (x-i)^2}$$ you face two types and integral
$$I_k=\int \frac {\cos(x)}{x+ik}\,dx \qquad \text{and} \qquad J_k=\int \frac {\cos(x)}{(x+ik)^2}\,dx $$ where $k=\pm 1$.

Make $x+ik=y$ and expand the cosine

$$\cos(y-ik)=\cosh (k) \cos (y)-i \sinh (k) \sin (y)$$ So, now, we have four kinds of integrals
$$\int \frac {\sin(y)}y \,dy \qquad \int \frac {\cos(y)}y \,dy \qquad \int \frac {\sin(y)}{y^2} \,dy \qquad \int \frac {\cos(y)}{y^2} \,dy$$ The first and second leads to the sine and cosine integrals; for the the third and the fourth use one integration by parts.

Go back to $x$, use the bounds and simplify all complex numbers.

Comment: Could you explain in more details: "where $k=\pm1$ is an imaginary number"?

Comment: @user. Sorry ! I shall edit.